# How can I disable pre-fill form fields in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email

I'm making a to-do list with Rails. Therefore I made a user-model(email and password). I want that the user will be able to edit there account so I made a edit and update action on the user controller I also have a user model. Everything works great but my issue is that on the settings view the text_field for updating the email is already prefilled with their current email adress in the model. I want to disable the prefilling because of design aspects (content of the placeholder should be readable right away). I know that when I will solve this problem, there will be another issue with the user model. For example if a user only wants to change the password the user will get an error message such as:  "Email can't be blank" and "Email is Invalid"... I was able to modify the minimum length validation for the password if the password is blank because I knew that "has_secure_password" enforces presence validations upon object creation. So I knew new users won't be able to sign up with blank passwords. But how can I create the same effect for the email validation? I haven't found a solution yet, I would really appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Questions:

1. How to disable the pre-fill form in Rails?
2. What should be modified to accept blank emails in the settings form
   without updating the email to blank in database?

**users_controller.rb (controller)**

```
def edit
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update 
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated!"
  redirect_to @user
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end
```

**edit.html.erb (view)**

```
<% provide(:title, "Settings") %>
<h4>SETTINGS</h4>

<h5>User Edit</h5>
<%= @user.email %>
<div class="settings">
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'layouts/error_messages' %>

  <p>Change Email:</p>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "New Email", class: "formfield" %>

  <p>Change Password:</p>
  <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "New Password", class: "formfield" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "New Password Confirmation", class: "formfield" %>


  <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "form_button" %>
 <% end %>

 <%= link_to "Delete my Account", '#' %>
</div>
```

**user.rb (model)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                     format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                 uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
 has_secure_password
 validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true

 # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
 def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
 end
end
```

Comment: As you are using form_for,it will bind and show the model values in the view..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to disable the pre-fill form in Rails?

Adding `value: nil` for the `field` you want to disable pre-fill will do.

For example,

```
<%= f.text_field :email, value: nil, placeholder: "New Email", class: "formfield" %>
```

> What should be modified to accept blank emails in the settings form
>   without updating the email to blank in database?

Erase `presence: true` in the ***email validation***.

```
validates :email, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Comment: Allow blank will allow nil to be saved to the database for email won't it?

Comment: @japed Bit confused, also `:allow_blank` is ignored by the `presence` validator. Updated.

Comment: but I think he wants it so that if they have an email it doesn't display in the form, but if they don't enter anything then it will remain the same.  Allow blank will set it in the database to nil won't it?  I could be wrong....

Comment: Thanks value: nil disabled the prefill! But when I delete the presence: true email validation then I still have one more error message because of the REGEX email validation... and if I will delete this I obviously won't have any validation for sign up! So I know ":allow_blank" will skip the error messages in settings but it will also save/update the email as blank in the database :/

I want a form without a prefill and if they won't enter anything then it will still remain the same email in the database without update to blank...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
You have to add attribute with `value=nil` for the first time in your edit form to keep your placeholder show up.

```
<%= f.text_field :email, value: nil, placeholder: "New Email", class: "formfield" %>
```

Then, to avoid a validation in your model you can add value email in your controller before validation. For instance:

```
def update 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  user_params[:email] = @user.email if params[:user][:email].nil?
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

I hope it can help you

Comment: Sorry that I reply that late but I have been on vacation... Thanks for your help but it didn't work neither the validation doenst allow that :/

Comment: Those are the errors: "The form contains 2 errors. Email can't be blank Email is invalid".
This is because of the user model validation and it is necessary for the registration process otherwise people can register without a valid email adress... I have no clue how I could modify the model to allow this expectation in the user settings... If you don't know the answer but you know a book or any sources where I could find an answer I would be very happy!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just use form_tag, instead of form_for

like so <%= form_tag '/some_url' do %> 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

To allow blank emails in your validation add allow_blank: true

```
validates :email, length: { maximum: 255 },
          format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
          uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
          allow_blank: true
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank
Validating both presence and allow_blank does not make sense.

Comment: Your solution updates the email to blank in the database and users can register with blank emails... this was not the goal but thanks for trying.
Registration should be with email validation and users should not be able to register with blank emails. Exceptation is in the user settings if the email form is empty then the email should remain the same without updating to blank otherwise if something is typed in the emailform the validation should work again.

Thanks to Pavan I know how to disable the prefill. Just giving a value of nil in the form disables the prefill.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Maybe not the solution you are looking for but you could clear the field with javascript.

2 - You can use conditional validations, from the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, unless: :email_present?

  def email_present?
    self.email.blank?
  end
end
```

**Code not tested**, but must be close to a working solution.

Comment: Not really because it will also allow blank registraion on the signup view! :(  I want a form without a prefill and if the user won't enter anything then it will still remain the same in the database without update to blank... This should be an expectation and only possible on the user settings... 
I guess I could maybe do this with a before_validation call on update only to reset the the email to the stored value before the validations kicks in but I have no idea how I can accomplish this only on the user settings views... :/
Thanks for trying!